# Recent Qt repository

Tags: ppa, qt, official-repositories, qt-creator, qt5

Is there any repository for latest Qt versions (recent version is 5.0.1 while ubuntu has 4.8) ?

**PS**

I found [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-qt5-edgers/+archive/qt5-daily) but it tagged as [deprecated]!!!, so I'm wondering what if there is official one by Canonical.

Answer (score 1):

Read on

DEPRECATED.

Please use https://launchpad.net/~canonical-qt5-edgers/+archive/qt5-proper for near-final pure Qt5 on Ubuntu 12.10, and https://launchpad.net/~canonical-qt5-edgers/+archive/qt5-beta1 for Ubuntu Phone application development on Ubuntu 12.10 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

qt5-proper will be later updated to final Qt5 and to be suitable to replace qt5-beta1 for all purposes.

The PPAs are not needed anymore, all of Qt 5.0.1 is now in the Ubuntu 13.04 archives. Just install 'ubuntu-sdk'! ~found here https://launchpad.net/~canonical-qt5-edgers/+archive/qt5-proper

Comment: I read the above note mentioned in [deprecated]. I'm looking for final OR official repository

Comment: The PPAs are not needed anymore, all of Qt 5.0.1 is now in the Ubuntu 13.04 archives. Just install 'ubuntu-sdk'! ~found here https://launchpad.net/~canonical-qt5-edgers/+archive/qt5-proper

Comment: I'm Unable to find "ubuntu-sdk" although I added "qt5-proper" PPA.... I'm using ubutnu 12.10